# Is any other way of using boolean AND query with two documents can treat as single document in lucene?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have two documents to search, and I want to use Lucene for boolean AND query with different approach. Which means I want to perform boolean AND with two documents can be treated as single one and perform search on resulted single document.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, or perhaps post a little piece of code/pseudo code that illustrates what you want to do? Your question is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is the MultiFieldQueryParser..it allows you to search on multiple fields from a single document.